# How to use :hover to show another box next to it's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<style type = "text/css">
.privacycheck2:hover {
        background-color: #E60000;
        width: 100px;
        left: 860px;
        position: relative;
}
.privacycheck2 {
        position: relative;
        top: 225px;
        left: 852px;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        font-size: 19px;
        color: white;
        }
.privacycheck1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 265px;
        background-color: #E60000;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        left: 843px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 5px #E60000;
        }
</style>
<body>
<div class = "privacycheck2:hover">This information is private</div>
<div class = "privacycheck1"></div>
<div class = "privacycheck2">i</div>
</body>
```

How do I make so if you `hover` over `privacycheck1`, it will show a box next to `privacycheck1` that says "This information is private"
The code I wrote also makes it when you `hover` over `privacycheck1`, it would make `privacycheck2` (the "I") would move and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Have you tried using `+` or `~` selector?

Comment: @Pangloss, can you give me an example and write a code of how that works? Thanks man.

Comment: i.e. `privacycheck2:hover + privacycheck1 {...}`

Comment: @Pangloss, I tried it but it doesn't show anything next to privacycheck1

Comment: I'm not so sure about the question, but there is no previous/parent selector in plain CSS.

Comment: Is you class really `privacycheck2:hover `? I'd suggest to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this, although you would have to rewrite your HTML.

```css
.privacycheck1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #E60000;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 5px #E60000;   
}

.privacycheck1::before {
    content: 'i';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 30px;
}

.privacycheck1:hover::before {
    content: 'This information is private';
}
```

```html
<div class="privacycheck1"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting closer and I see what you are doing. Can you write down a code where the `content` will show in a `red div box` so it looks better. Can you also explain what `content` does in CSS and HTML. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed the red box issue but can you explain to me what `content` does. Thanks.

Comment: `content` is a special attribute for `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. Here's an article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Boot Strap, you can use built in functionality of tool-tip.
**Otherwise**
Try this :

```
<body>
<style type = "text/css">
.privacycheck1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 265px;
    background-color: #E60000;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 843px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 5px #E60000;
}

.hoverEle {
    display:none;
}
.privacycheck1:hover .hoverEle {
    display:block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
</style>

<div class = "privacycheck1">
    <div class="hoverEle">This information is private</div>
</div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix up CSS and javascript to do this.

```
<html>
<style type = "text/css">
.privacycheck1 {

    top: 265px;
    background-color: #E60000;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 843px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 5px #E60000;

    /// set display none
    display:none;

    }       
#privacycheck2_hover{
position: absolute;
margin-left:30px;
display:none;  // initially set its display to none

}
</style>
<body>
<div id = 'privacycheck2_hover'>This information is private</div>
<div class = "privacycheck1" onMouseOver="showOn()"  onMouseOut="showOff()"></div>

<script>
// when mouse out set css display mode to block
function showOn(){      
    document.getElementById("privacycheck2_hover").style.display = 'block';

}
// when mouse over set css display mode off
function showOff(){
    document.getElementById("privacycheck2_hover").style.display = 'none';      
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `display` do?

Comment: It worked for you?? setting display:none, tells the browser not to render this HTML element. Setting it back to display: block or display : table, render it back